# Ability for moderators to annotate posts as you can annotate users

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderation, moderators, annotations

Sometimes on *[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)*, we use flags for moderator attention to communicate among moderators (about something specific to a question or answer).

It'd be nice if this was explicitly supported by the ability to annotate posts; I know we have chat, but this would be more asynchronous, and it could also be used to leave notes/reminders for your future self.

I don't know where in the UI I'd put it, but functionally it'd be like comments only visible to moderators.

Comment: I like this idea.  I usually either favorite or comment on stuff I want to get back to later, and neither of those works exactly right for this purpose.

Comment: This idea can be useful to note why a question was removed from the HNQ.

Comment: A comment visible only to moderators, you mean write a comment and then delete it; I've done that, and I'm not a moderator; it let's you write additional information not shown to all users but still useful with the visible comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I don't know where in the UI I'd put it

I imagine it could be identical to the mod link on a user page; it would show a number next to the mod link on the post:

[image: Mockup of the interface]

Answer (score 1):

Since it's been nearly two years on this answer, I'd like to point out that annotations are best made to the poster's account, if the infraction is severe enough (i.e. a misdemeanor).  Every account has a moderator flag history anyway, so it's pretty easy to find the infractions, and suspensions take care of the felonies.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is with the post itself and not the user, that's what motivated my request