# Streamline moderators contacting users through chat

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, chat, moderator-tools

If a moderator needs to contact a user (and it's not severe enough to warrant a moderator message), it's common to make a private room and ping them. The procedure is:

1. Create a new chatroom (named "Room for UserA and UserB")
2. Superping the user with some stub message so a chat account is created for them
3. Find the user's chat account through the 'control access' menu of the chat room.
4. Add them to the room's write ACL
5. Make the room private
6. Post the actual message

This takes more time than it looks like. Is it possible to add something to the chat room creation page that takes a chat ID or site+UID (same as the superping dialog) and automatically does all that?

Comment: If anything, it probably should work similarly to how "let's take this to chat" link for comments on questions and answers is.

Comment: Its so complex that I don't even bother.  Would be nice if the process *was* streamlined so that it was as easy as clicking a link on their profile and adding a title to the room.  Perhaps add a little "so mods" so that mods get pinged as well, thus keeping the discussion in the open as with "private" messages.

Comment: Has this not even been implemented yet? It'd be nice if it was simpler to start a private chat with a user for moderation reasons.

Comment: Related: [Add "invite user to chat" function on main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70385/add-invite-user-to-chat-function-on-main-site)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that it should be significantly easier for moderators to create a chat with a specific user.  I've gone ahead and written this up [internally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l) and thrown it into the backlog to be reviewed and possibly implemented.  Once the team reviews it, then it will either move to the devs or be kicked to a later date.

I'll put a [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) on this for the time being, and hopefully this will come to fruition soon.

Comment: Two years later

Answer (score 82):

I would propose a link on the mod menu for a user

[image]

(super sensitive mod options, like **merge**, removed!)

That does the following things:

1. Creates the chat room "Private chat with user Foo" *if it doesn't automatically exist*
2. Gives Foo write access
3. Opens that chat room in a new tab
4. Automatically places a link in Foo's inbox telling him that he should join that chat room

This would turn a ten step process into a one step, and would also allow mods to forego leaving comments to reply to flags or other concerns.

Do this.  **I say so.**

---

**Also, I'll award the bounty to the best hand-drawn (in mspaint or other digital media--no hand drawn crap on notebook paper) image of a narwhal.

I will tineye that bastard, so don't cheat.**

Comment: -1 This answer is currently not useful for me.

Comment: @TomWijsman Why do you care? It's not like you're a moderator. This is also a perfectly fine answer to a feature request.

Comment: OK, what is super sensitive in the "Submit" button? `:)`

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I think he was joking.  This answer has no downvote.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: OMG SSSH QUIET!!!!

Comment: Can you tell them to do this too? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63649/ability-to-annotate-posts-as-you-can-annotate-users

Comment: @JuanManuel: Dude, you've got more meta rep than me.  USE IT.  Its worthless otherwise.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Why do you care? It's not like you've put this answer. This is also a perfectly fine answer to a feature request. But yes, was a joke, because hey... It's Friday!

Comment: @TomWijsman I guess I need to recalibrate my humor sensors :P

Comment: ["hand-drawn in mspaint image of a narwhal"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfx5R.png)

Comment: As a new Mod, I am seriously struggling to wrap my soft head around contacting users for a chat, rather than having to send a message that get's CC'd around every other mod.  It's way too difficult.  If the automation exists to create a room after too many comments on a question, it cannot be too hard to expose that functionality in the mod button as per this answer.

Comment: @Wont - I noticed no one drew you a Narwhal! Well, free of charge ;) http://i.imgur.com/o9REnM3.png

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure that this would even be limited to moderators. Giving users the ability to create chat rooms easily from questions or answers and perhaps automatically generating comments directing users to those rooms might be a good idea, as well. I think that Chat is underutilized, and streamlining the process of creating chat rooms for extended discussion would be awesome.

Comment: This existed when chat first launched, and they got rid of it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I was unaware of that. Is there any reason given for why it was removed? A Meta thread or blog post that referenced it?