# Why do diamond mods have the ability to mark their own flags as helpful?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools, helpful-flags

I am a [mod](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/86), newly diamonded, and still learning the ropes.  I added a test flag onto a post in my site's meta, to see what would happen on my side of the world.  Sure enough, the flag came up in the queue, and to my surprise, I was able to immediately mark it helpful.  While I understand why mods might need to flag (rather than immediately act) in case they're not sure, I'm not sure when it would ever be helpful to let them mark their own flags as helpful.

I don't necessarily believe that anyone who got to the stage of being a diamond mod would abuse this just for a stinkin' badge or two, but why is the option there?  Am I missing a possible usefulness?

Comment: So *that's* how all the moderators got their Marshall badges when it was created...

Comment: I think a better question would be, why *wouldn't* they have the ability to mark their own flags?  At that level, you're supposed to know what's helpful and you are assumed to have the integrity to not abuse the system, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Then you don't need to flag in the first place - just act.

Comment: @animuson: [So *that's* how moderators *should* get their Marshal badges.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127493/arent-moderators-eligible-for-the-deputy-and-marshal-badges-too-or-has-it-chan)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs It defeats the purpose of flagging if the flagger already knows what to do, and can do it; and if s/he doesn't know what to do, and flags, s/he shouldn't mark it as helpful, because s/he doesn't know.

Comment: Sometimes I flag when I'm involved in the question, for example when a NAA appears in a question where I have a competing answer. I know what to do, just don't want to do it. A couple of times, when in a rush, I flagged as a bookmark, a "I'll handle this later if the others don't take care of it"...

Comment: Occasionally I spot something when on my smartphone and I flag it for later - as some mod tools don't work well (especially trying to migrate questions!! Actually - I should raise that as a bug...)

Comment: Maybe handled flags should count toward Marshal and Deputy and then everyone can shut up about moderators abusing their power to get two stinking badges.

Comment: Checked my flags, and apparently at some point I flagged a post for moderation attention because I wasn't sure what to do with it, and a couple of minutes later, when I realised / remembered what needs be done, I dismissed my own flag with the "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" canned message (sweet irony ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos Betcha you wouldn't have done that in the flag weight days!

Comment: Related question that might be useful: [Can moderators handle flags cast on their own content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306740/can-moderators-handle-flags-cast-on-their-own-content?noredirect=1#comment997514_306740)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In addition to leaving "mental notes" as a couple folks mentioned in comments, some sites also use mod flags to talk about a specific question. Plus, if there are multiple flags on the same question, your only option is to either mark them all as helpful or as declined, even if some of the flags are by the mod themselves.

That said, if someone *really* wants to flag 500 posts and abuse their power to get a gold badge... more power to 'em, I guess, but their diamond and badge just might disappear.

Fun fact: if a moderator flags something as spam it basically flags the post and dismisses the flag as helpful right away, which triggers all the effects of a spam flag - deleting/locking the post, docking the poster 100 rep, etc. So there's an example of where this is actually useful.

Comment: Try and stop me!

Comment: In principle, the 100 rep dock could be a powerful tool.  In practice, most spammers won't earn enough rep for the 100 rep dock to matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Very true, although I've seen it kick in for people who've gotten away with excessive promotion or had a bad day and posted something spectacularly offensive.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - not true. The post is marked as deleted (and locked) by Community but your flag is marked has "helpful".

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn If you've experienced that, I think you might be confusing that with the Community user stealing *handled* flags bug, which I think is fixed

Comment: These reasons are sufficient.  I'll proceed to discreetly hold my peace...

Comment: RE: Talk about a post: [Ability to annotate posts as you can annotate users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63649/ability-to-annotate-posts-as-you-can-annotate-users)