# Comment flags on admin/posts/<post id>/show-flags are always shown as type "Comment: Offensive"

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, flags, moderator-tools

When looking on `admin/posts/<post id>/show-flags`, I noticed that flags for comments are always reported as "Comment: Offensive" even while the flag was a different one.

[image: screenshot]

To be sure the user didn't use a custom reason for the flag, which was the erroneously reported as a flag for offensive comment, I tried flagging a comment as not constructive, and what I obtained is this:

[image: screenshot]

Apparently, any comment is marked as "Comment: Offensive," even in the case the user entered a custom reason.

[image: screenshot]

Comment flags should be reported as "Comment" type, if the same type is used for all the flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, there was only one type of comment flag - "offensive". Distinct flag types for the various comment flag options were added in June of 2013, and began appearing in the flag list shortly thereafter.