# Please change the text on the rate-limiting error message related to comment interaction

Tags: bug, comments

I am aware of [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote) - this is not a dupe because I am not asking to have the rate-limiting made more specific, but rather to have the error message adjusted.

You can't interact with comments **in any way** more frequently than every 5 seconds. You can't flag, delete your own, or upvote. Say for example I read someone's comment, delete mine and flag theirs as obsolete - I get a message saying I can only vote on comments every 5 seconds. There was no voting. There was deleting, and there was flagging.

Proposed new text: `non-edit interactions with comments are limited to once per 5 seconds. Dismiss this note to reset the clock.`

The extra sentence is because if you angrily stare at the error message for 10 seconds, then dismiss it and try to do your action with the comment, you will just get the error again, and that always makes me even more ticked off, so if someone is going to change the text, let's take care of that too.

Comment: There is a flaw with that explanation. You *can* edit a comment more than in less 5 seconds. Editing is an interaction.

Comment: I'm going to test that by editing this comment then upvoting yours, if i can.

Comment: It's true, right after I edited my comment I could upvote @Lix's comment. And right after I submitted this one I could start an edit on my previous one, or this one. So ` non-edit-interactions` should start the error message

Comment: While I agree from the perspective that people seem to get confused by this fairly regularly, you are voting to delete a comment like you vote to delete your own post, and flagging is ultimately [just voting to delete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147313/comment-flags-on-admin-posts-post-id-show-flags-are-always-shown-as-type-comm/147320#147320) someone else's comment...so the message clarification seems more like a [meta-tag:feature-request] to me.

Comment: But @Tim, I can delete my own post or comment without anyone else's interaction (well, with questions there are some exceptions). So while technically the system may implement that as a "vote" it is not really a vote in the logical sense. The prompt when I delete a comment does not say "Really vote to delete this comment?" and I don't need anyone else to agree with me in order to do so.