# Flagging a comment as moderator deletes it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A moderator flag on a comment silently deletes it even if the “other” option is selected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136603/a-moderator-flag-on-a-comment-silently-deletes-it-even-if-the-other-option-is)

On rare occasions, there are very difficult to handle posts where I would want another moderator to look and make the decision, so that the action is not unilateral.

An example of such which came up recently is a comment which I find offensive or nonconstructive, which also specifically references me.  Since there might be a conflict of interest if I were to take the action into my own hands, I would want another moderator to look at it.

I decided to flag the comment, and it simply deleted it.  This created far more problems overall.

I am aware that using the moderator chat would be an alternative solution, and I plan to use this in the future, but currently I don't understand why a moderator flagging a comment deletes it.

Comment: Moderator super powers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases flags count as votes, e.g. spam and offensive flags. If enough flags are cast, the post is deleted. The moderator powers are very consistent in this regard, in **any** voting decision a moderator vote is binding.

Comment flags also auto-delete, so it fits the general behavior that mod flags also delete comments.

Comments are expendable, if you considered it offensive enough I'm sure other users would find that as well, and that is reason enough to delete a comment.

If you really want to ask other mods on a comment, either flag the parent post or ping them in chat.

Comment: Perfect, this answers it.  I will make a note to never flag a comment in the future.

Comment: Note that some comments can be insta-nuked on first complaint.  Any comment mentioning "accept rate", for example, can disappear immediately when being flagged as non-constructive/off-topic.