# Does a moderator who flags a comment with a custom reason automatically delete the comment?

Tags: support, comments, moderators, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flagging a comment as moderator deletes it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160543/flagging-a-comment-as-moderator-deletes-it)

In the site where I am moderator, I flagged a comment because it was rude toward me for a comment I left about the answer not answering the question. I flagged it with a custom reason, in the same way I would have done for an answer given to my question, or a question for which I answered too. The purpose was to make another moderator chime in.

Right after I flagged the comment, the comment was deleted, differently from what happens when I flag an answer with a custom reason.
Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: I think it's same like reviewing suggested edits: binding vote. Still looking for official proof though.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But when a moderator flags a post using a custom reason, the post is not deleted.

Comment: Yep. [Official answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147320/152859) on one of you own questions. "...and moderator flags are binding (regardless of which reason is chosen)" - the code behind for comments is different than posts guess that's just one of those differences. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, I forgot that question. `:)` It is because a flag comment is always seen from the system as a flag for an offensive comment, which is a binding flag for moderators. That is not indeed what happens with posts. Thank you for reminding me of my own answer. `:)`

Comment: No worries, happened to me too! (asking something just to be reminded I already got answer in one of my own past questions)